# actionBar = getActionBar() - "application stopped unexpectedly" in old mobile set

Tags: android

`actionBar = getActionBar();` is working fine  In most of the new mobile sets,  but in some old set it give error  -

> "application stopped unexpectedly"

Can somebody please tell me why it is so, or is there any alternatives for `getActionBar()`, like `actionbar = new ActionBar()`. I am not using support.v7

Comment: Start using support.v7. Otherwise you just dream of non-existent classes to become available for you, just becuase you do not want to use support library. Here is a tutorial that should help you with that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6TGgYqfJnyc&feature=youtu.be

Comment: can you post the code where you are calling getActionBar()? If you want to support older devices you've to use` AppCompactActivity` and call `getSupportActionBar()`

Answer (score 2):

Start using v7 appcompat library, as it is the only way.
Read this : https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html#v7

1. Add this line in the build.gradle and re-sync:
   `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'`.
2. Refractor your activity classes by extending to `AppCompactActivity` instead of `Activity`.
3. If you've set custom action bar, call `setSupportActionBar([your_custom_toolbar])` in `OnCreate()` method.
4. You can now call `getSupportActionBar()` error-free :)

Answer (score 0):

in your onCreate() function use this line to set your ActionBar.

```
getSupportActionBar().show();
```

Hope it solves the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Older devices that you are using don't have the ActionBar; so the application crashes when you try to access it.

So, to support ActionBar on older devices, you can use the support library and use **`getSupportActionBar()`** to access it.

Instead of using the plain vanilla Activity, you should be using **[ActionBarActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html)** to be able to use the getSupportActionBar() method.